# Implement Shopware 6 Payment method fees

Tags: shopware

How is it possible to add a fee for a specific payment method? Ideally based on the customer / a rule as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently (Shopware v6.3.5.1) not a standard function.
You can check the [Shopware Feature Roadmap](https://www.shopware.com/de/roadmap/) to see when it will be available.

Nevertheless you can now write a plugin and subscribe to the payment-selection and implement your own fees.

Comment: thanks, but as far as I can see it's not on the roadmap. We ended up implementing af custom plugin for this, yes.